# Lob returns null using play framework and Ebean and H2

Tags: java, playframework, h2, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am developing a program with play 2.3(with Ebean and H2) for java. I have a model like this:

```
@Entity
public class DeviceModel extends Model implements PathBindable<DeviceModel> {

@Id
public Long id;


@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public byte[] picture;

...
```

In my controller I have a function which writes a picture as `byte[]` inside a `DeviceModel` object and calls the `update()` function. so now the picture should be saved in database.

And i have this function to show the picture:

```
public static Result picture(Long id) {
    final DeviceModel deviceModel = DeviceModel.findByID(id);
    if (deviceModel == null){
        return notFound();
    }
    return ok(deviceModel.picture);
}
```

the funny thing is that `deviceModel.picture` is null!

but in my view, I have this:

```
        @if(deviceModel.picture != null) {
                show the picture!
        } else{
            do something else
        }
```

but here, `deviceModel.picture` is not null!!! and MOST OF THE TIMES the picture will be shown correctly!!

I deleted the `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` but it didn't solve the problem.

any Idea why is it like this?

Comment: Just a guess: Your template is actually using the getPicture() method instead of accessing directly the field. Maybe you have some additional code in this method that somehow transforms the picture's byte[]?

Comment: thanks for the hint. as a solution, i made my picture field private, and made getter and setter my self. now with getPicture() I always get the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around for this issue, but I still like to know the reason, why accessing the picture field directly, returns null.

here is the work around:
I just made my `picture` field private, and made getter and setter my self. now in my Controller, with `getPicture()` I always get the data

```
@Entity
public class DeviceModel extends Model implements PathBindable<DeviceModel> {

@Id
public Long id;


@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] picture;


public byte[] getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(byte[] picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that behavior is the `FetchType.LAZY` (which apparently is also the default for Lobs). It tells Ebean to fetch the data lazily, i.e. not immediately when you load the object, but only when you actually access it.

As Ebean cannot detect the access when you go directly at the field (`picture`), the loading doesn't happen at all and you get `null`.

By using `getPicture()`, the code of which is *enhanced* by Ebean, it knows to load the data before returning the value.

You can **overcome that behavior by simply using `FetchType.EAGER`**. But you should only do that, if you're sure you need the data always, because it takes more time and memory (e.g. in your example, if you have 100s of pictures and you only want to show a list of names, it would not be necessary to load all the pictures' actual image data as well.

Comment: This is exactly the correct solution for me as @behzad solution didn't work